# How can I render to texture in single mip-level?

Tags: rendering, directx9

I'm trying to implement Hi-Z Screen-Space Cone-Traced Reflections using Direct3D9. I already know how to render to specific mip-level texture using Direct3D11, but not using Direct3D9.

Has anyone tried the same before?

How would I generate a custom mip-texture using D3D9? Not just switch between two different sized textures from system memory.

Maybe something involving StretchRect functions might work?

Answer (score 1):

Create your mipmapped texture as a rendertarget. Then grab the surfaces of each Mip level you want to render to like this:

`D3DXCreateTexture( device, width, height, numMips, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, texFormat, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &texture );
texture->GetSurfaceLevel( 0, &mipLevel0 );
texture->GetSurfaceLevel( 1, &mipLevel1 );
texture->GetSurfaceLevel( 2, &mipLevel2 );
...`

Then to render to the specified mipmap in the texture use `SetRenderTarget` with the appropriate surface. e.g.
`device->SetRenderTarget( 0, mipLevel2 );`